# Can ACS Service Namespace creation be automated?

Tags: azure, wif, acs

First, let me state my *real* problem: I've got code that makes calls to the ACS Management service, and I'd like my integration tests to be able to be run concurrently without each test run clobbering the others. That is, since multiple people / build servers might end up running these tests concurrently, if they're all using the same ACS service namespace, concurrency issues arise.

My thinking is the simplest means of achieving this would be to generate new, unique ACS service namespaces for each test runner -- but as far as I can tell, there's no automated way of creating new service namespaces (or management client keys). Am I wrong? Is there another way of going about this?

An automated method of creating new service namespaces would be extraordinarily helpful.

Comment: I think that including an actuall call to a service is general fault in your unit testing. Are you testing your code, or are you testing ACS service? If you are testing your code, the best option is to mock something. Right now I can't find the best mocking point, but running tests against a live web/whatever service does not seem like testing code, but testing service instead. There are dozen of reasons of why would your test fail, that are not your code's problem. Imagine lost internet connectivity, imagine temporary service unavailability, imagine network timeout, etc...

Comment: ref.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972845/how-to-test-a-client-of-a-wcf-service

Comment: @astaykov in his question he refers to integration testing and not unit testing

Comment: Astaykov, as Sandrino points out, I'm talking about integration testing, not unit testing. So, just like in other forms of integration testing where you use a real, but not production db (think using SQLite instead of your real SQL Server instance to test all your db calls / orm mappings/ etc.), I'm using a real ACS service namespace, just not the real production one, since there is, unfortunately, no ACSLite :).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. That's not possible today. Maybe you can describe your scenario in more detail and there might be some alternative solutions to avoid having to recreate the namespace?

Comment: My scenario specifically is that I'm using ACS as a federation provider for multiple identity providers, and I'm writing part of the tooling that will allow administrators to add their identity provider info as a part of the onboarding / administration process on my service. So, I've written code on my side that calls all the ACS management service API stuff, and associated integration tests. Just trying to keep integration tests from stepping all over each other if they run concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it should be possible, since the Management Portal is a Silverlight application accessing a WCF RIA Service.

If you dig deep enough you'll find some useful information:

- This is the Silverlight XAP for the management of Windows Azure AppFabric: https://appfabricportal.windows.azure.com/ClientBin/Microsoft.AppFabric.WebConsole.4.1.3.xap
- This is the service being used when listing/creating/... namespaces etc..: https://appfabricportal.windows.azure.com/Services/Microsoft-AppFabric-Web-Services-AppFabricDomainService.svc?wsdl

And this is a piece of the DomainContext:

```
  public sealed class AppFabricDomainContext : DomainContext
  {

    public AppFabricDomainContext(Uri serviceUri)
      : this((DomainClient) new WebDomainClient<AppFabricDomainContext.IAppFabricDomainServiceContract>(serviceUri, true))
    {
    }

    ...

    public InvokeOperation CreateServiceNamespace(IEnumerable<string> serviceNames, string parentProjectKey, string serviceNamespace, IEnumerable<string> packageKeys, string regionKey, Action<InvokeOperation> callback, object userState)
    {
      Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
      dictionary.Add("serviceNames", (object) serviceNames);
      dictionary.Add("parentProjectKey", (object) parentProjectKey);
      dictionary.Add("serviceNamespace", (object) serviceNamespace);
      dictionary.Add("packageKeys", (object) packageKeys);
      dictionary.Add("regionKey", (object) regionKey);
      this.ValidateMethod("CreateServiceNamespace", (IDictionary<string, object>) dictionary);
      return this.InvokeOperation("CreateServiceNamespace", typeof (void), (IDictionary<string, object>) dictionary, true, callback, userState);
    }
  }
```

Finding this info was the easy part, getting it to work... that's something else. Take the authentication part for example, you'll need to authenticate with Windows Live and use those credentials when calling the WCF RIA Service.

Good luck!

Comment: Ha, wow, I hadn't considered opening up the xap to see what the management portal is actually doing, pretty clever, Sandrino. That said, I have to imagine this isn't a *supported* scenario :)